# Is that possible to change UI of Windows from usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I want to change Content of Button, from a usercontrol on WPF

Consider this is MainWindows:

```
<Window  Name="window1">
<Button content="1" Name="btnWindow" />
<Usercontrol Name="UserControlwindow" />
</Window>
```

And on Usercontrol, I have a button:

```
<UserControl Name="usercontrol1">
<Button content="change content of btnWindow form here" Name="btnUsercontrol" />
</UserControl>
```

When user try to touch "btnUsercontrol", I want to see button(content of button) of main window changes.

Comment: declare a dependency property in a UserControl "UserControlwindow". Bind btnWindow `Content` to that DP. profit!

Comment: @ASh thanks, How should I prepare it?